# select() not responding?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

The objective of my program is to use select to manage multiple sockets. However, I thought of trying it with one socket first. Now, the problem that I am facing is that initially client sends data to server, and server receives it and displays it, but then when client again sends some data, the server code remains still at select command.

here are some snippets that will give you an idea of how I am initializing the socket.

```
if((master_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
      exit(1);
    }

    if((bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&req, sizeof(req))) < 0)
    {
      exit(1);
    }

    listen(master_socket, 5);
    FD_SET(master_socket,&listening);

    /* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
    len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    while(1)
     {
            FD_ZERO(&listening);  //Flush out everything in socket
        FD_SET(master_socket,&listening); // Add master
        if(f_client>0)           // Add client if any
        {
            FD_SET(f_client,&listening);
        }
        printf("Checking for new connection \n");
           //Timeout is null, so waiting indefinitely
        rc = select(FD_SETSIZE, &listening, NULL, NULL, NULL);

     if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &listening))
        {
          printf("Master side invoked\n");
          if((f_client = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&req, &len)) < 0)
          {
             exit(1);
              }
            }

    else if (FD_ISSET(f_client,&listening))
    {
         if ((valread = read( f_client , buf, 1024)) == 0)
         {
            close(f_client);
            f_client=0;
         }
         else
         {
            fputs(buf, stdout);  
         }

    }
```

}

Basically in above program, it connects to the server, maintains a file descriptor for client `f_client` and add it. And in every round, it clears the socket, add master socket, and client socket if any, and then checks. Problem here is, first time it works, but second time when client sends some data. it gets hang to `rc = select(FD_SETSIZE, &listening, NULL, NULL, NULL);`

I am not to understand what is wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: sorry.. I will just edit that.. it should be master_socket

Comment: Fix your indentation, looks like your `else if fd_isset(f_client)` isn't at the level you indentation makes it appear to be.

Comment: Your code can only handle one client at a time.

Comment: Right now, yes. But that one client should be able to send message whenever it wants, right

Comment: 100% confirm it gets stuck in `select`, 100% confirm `f_client` is not zero, and 100% confirm the code didn't already read the data.

Comment: You are telling that, or asking me?

Comment: Those are the three most likely explanations for your problem. I'd say the most likely one is that you actually already read the data and don't realize it.

Comment: 100% confirm it gets stuck in select.. 100% confirm f_client is not zero.. but 100% not confirm if I already read the data.. But i am reading the data later, not before that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     if ((valread = read( f_client , buf, 1024)) == 0)
     {
        close(f_client);
        f_client=0;
     }
     else
     {
        fputs(buf, stdout);  
     }
```

This code is broken. The `fputs` function can *only* be used with a C-style string. You just have arbitrary data with no particular structure. Since you ignore `valread`, you also have no idea how many bytes you read. (Think about it, how could `fputs` possibly know how many bytes to output? That information is only in `valread`, and you don't pass it that information.)

You've already received the data, this broken code just threw it away. If you log `valread`, you'll see that you actually already read it in your last call to `read` before the call to `select` that hung.

instead of `fputs`, you could use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valread; ++i)
   putchar(buf[i]);
```

Comment: That is not possible.. After the data is outputted (first time), it goes back to "checking for new connection" and wait at select.. then I send some data from client, but it doesnt move

Comment: What are you using as a client? (And you should definitely fix this bug anyway. It would be the next problem you run into.)

Comment: I would fix it.. and what are you using as a client means? Like what connection.. TCP! sorry I didnt understand that question

Comment: You say "then I send some data from client". What is this "client" you are speaking of? It is a program you wrote? Is it a tool? How did you confirm it actually sent anything?

Comment: Thanks! your question solved my problem :) and thanks for that fputs advice.. thank you!